# Is there way to get any user's public details using user id in facebook in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, npm

I want to get user details in facebook using user id.But there is problem with Authentication.In facebook use OAuth 2 framework. Therefore it need to authorization to resource owner.Is there way to get users details in facebook using user id

Comment: Theres a couple of sdk's [here](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=facebook%20and%20node) but to my knowledge you need user permission to access their details

Comment: Thank you @Craicerjack
But in graph api console we can get users public details without authentication.If we give user id it give all public details in graph api console

Comment: this is not possible without user permission. Each user of which you want his details in your app has to permit your app to access it. There is no other way around this.

Comment: Yes but that is on Facebooks site. Within your own app you need to apply for the users permission. Facebook doesnt allow you to just access user data outside of their environment. Users have given facebook permission to use their data. If you want to use it they have to give it to your app too.

Comment: I have use 'fb' npm module.Then it gave only users id and user name only.If I give my facebook user id,it give all public details.I cannot get others public details.